# Error Al Encontrar Imagen HTML

Tags: html, css

El error que me sucede es que a la hora de ponerle una imagen a mi página web indicando el directoria, me da un error al abrirlo en Google Chrome, pero al hacer control y click en VS Code me abre la iagen, como indicando que el directorio de ésta está bien especificado, creo que el problema es que la página  web, es una subpágina de index, que está guardada en otra carpeta llamada Páginas, y al tener que hacer Undo da error.
Aquí la apariencia de la carpeta para daros una idea:
[image: La Página web de "decoración" es la que tiene el problema y está guardada en la carpeta páginas, mientras que las imágenes en su correspondiente carpeta]

La Página web de "decoración" es la que tiene el problema y está guardada en la carpeta páginas, mientras que las imágenes en su correspondiente carpeta.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Historia</title>
    
</head>

<div style="max-width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">

    <body>

        <h1 align="center" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 10vh; font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;">DECORACIÓN</h1>
        <img src="/Imágenes/decoracion.jpg">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 3vh;font-weight: bold; font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;"></p>
    </body>

</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el problema/error en concreto? ¿Hay algún mensaje de algo?, si lo hay, agrégalo a la pregunta. Si fuera tú, evitaría usar acentos y caracteres especiales en nombres de carpetas y archivos, si no hilas fino con la codificación esos caracteres pueden romper el código.

Answer (score 0):

Cierto, es un problema de acceso al archivo. En principio debiera funcionar si la carpeta Practica4 es la raíz del servidor donde esté instalada la página (¿localhost?).
Si la p´´agina donde está la imagen es la carpeta Páginas (Páginas\decoracion.html) puedes poner las url de los recursos de manera relativa a la página

```
   <img src = "../Imágenes/decoracion.jpg">
```

te va a pasar algo parecido con el archivo de estilos css al insertarlo en la página.
Y otra cosa, para evitar problemas con nombres yo usaría alfabeto internacional (o sea inlgés) sin acentos ni mayúsculas. Ten en cuenta que los servidores basados en Linux diferencias entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, y si desarrollas en windows esto puede ser una fuente de problemas.